# Rendering a string in django template as json object

Tags: javascript, django, jinja2

I have a angular app that sends json data to a django backend. The django app save the json data in to a DB and later pulls it out to send it back to the angular app. I am having trouble getting this whole chain to work right.

Here is where view to pass the json data back to the template.

```
def myview(request, uid):
    formrecord = FormData.objects.get(someid = uid)
    return render(request, 'myview.html', 'formdata':formrecord.data})
```

Here is what formrecord.data looks like before `render()` above gets called:

```
(Pdb) formrecord.data
u'{"user":{"firstName":"Bob","lastName":"Henderson"}}'
```

Here is my template

```
<script>
var mydata ={{ formdata }};
mydata = JSON.parse(mydata);
console.log(mydata);
</script>
```

Here is what gets rendered:

```
var mydata ={&quot;user&quot;:{&quot;firstName&quot;:&quot;Bob&quot;,&quot;lastName&quot;:&quot;Henderson&quot;}};
```

The JSON.parse(mydata) gives me a syntax error on the JS side. How I can get the JS to parse the string correctly into a JS object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `mydata` is not a string, you don't need to parse it as it's already a valid JS object: `var mydata ={"user":{"firstName":"Bob","lastName":"Henderson",}};`

You can go ahead and access properties like: `mydata.user.firstName`

Also, you should validate the JSON data you're storing in your model. The data you posted above is not valid, as in JSON the trailing comma is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

in js block use

```
<script>
  var mydata = JSON.parse("{{formdata|escapejs}}");
  console.log(mydata);
</script
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As @Arsh Singh said, `formrecord.data` is not a valid `json`, bit it's a valid `dict` for python, you can try like this:

```
# views
import json

def myview(request, uid):
    formrecord = FormData.objects.get(someid = uid)
    jsondata = json.dumps(formrecord.data)
    return render(request, 'myview.html', 'formdata':jsondata})
```

And then in JS block

```
<script>
  var mydata ={{ formdata }};
  console.log(mydata);
</script>
```

Comment: It's not actually a valid dict, It's a string (which represents an invalid JSON). `json.dumps` will expect a JSON serializable python object, which in this case is a string, so will print out a string (as opposed to a JSON object), and the value of mydata will be a string: `"{\\"user\\":{\\"firstName\\":\\"Bob\\",\\"lastName\\":\\"Henderson\\",}}"`

Answer (score 0):

You must use `|safe' in your JS file  like below:

## views

```
import json

def myview(request, uid):
    formrecord = FormData.objects.get(someid = uid)
    jsondata = json.dumps(formrecord.data)
    return render(request, 'myview.html', 'formdata':jsondata})
```

And then in JS block

```
<script>
  var mydata ={{ formdata|safe }};
  console.log(mydata);
</script>
```